# GDrive Search all files in MyDrive which are shared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have create this script:

```
function listAllFiles() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"' + MyAccount + '" in owners');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

How do I extend my filter so that I get back all files/directories that are mine and have been shared?

Who has a short example for me?

Thanks

```
function listAllFiles() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"' + MyAccount + '" in owners');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current stage, it seems that there is no query for directly searching only the shared files that you are the owner of. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms) So, in this case, it is required to modify the script. In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, Drive service (DriveApp) is used.

```js
function listAllFiles() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"' + MyAccount + '" in owners');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getSharingAccess() != DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE || file.getEditors().length > 0 || file.getViewers().length > 0) {
      Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, all shared files that you are the owner of are retrieved.

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, in this modification, Drive API v3 is used. So, [please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function listAllFiles2() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  let fileList = [];
  let pageToken;
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Files.list({ q: `'${MyAccount}' in owners and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false`, pageToken, pageSize: 1000, fields: "nextPageToken,files(id,name,shared)" });
    if (obj.files.length > 0) {
      fileList = [...fileList, ...obj.files.filter(({ shared }) => shared && shared === true)];
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  const fileNames = fileList.map(({name}) => name);
  console.log(fileNames)
}
```

#### Note:

- In your showing script, it seems that you want the filename. So, in this modification, the filenames are retrieved.

#### References:

- [Class File of DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: Many many thanks - scripting can be so ease :)

Comment: @J. Doe About `Many many thanks - scripting can be so ease :) `, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer